# Proper use of the verb "to need" when the subject is "bread"

Tags: verbs, conjugation

If I have multiple loaves of bread on the table, and I'm referring to all of them, which usage of the verb "need" is correct?

The bread *need* to be put in the fridge.

The bread *needs* to be put in the fridge.

Comment: Youssef, take a look at English Language Learners SE.  It has a lot to offer.

Comment: You don’t need to put bread in the fridge, and it will make it go soggy.

Answer (score 1):

A mass noun like "bread" is treated as a singular, so the correct conjugation is "needs".

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you refer to the bread. You can either describe it as a mass noun or you can describe it as a countable noun. The mass noun uses a singular verb, while the countable noun uses a plural verb:

> The *bread* <sup>(singular mass noun)</sup> ***needs*** <sup>(singular verb)</sup> to be put in the fridge.
>   The *loaves of bread* <sup>(plural countable noun)</sup> ***need*** <sup>(plural verb)</sup> to be put in the fridge.

You can even use the plural of *bread* without qualifying it with *loaves*. It's not as common, but it's still correct:

> The *breads* <sup>(plural countable noun)</sup> ***need*** <sup>(plural verb)</sup> to be put in the fridge.